# Adyen Web Drop In OnChange fires more than once

Tags: adyen

I have the Adyen Web Drop In integrated, which works fine. Now I want to add tracking so I can see when a customer changes the payment option or payment info. I use the OnSelect and OnChange event for this.

Problem:

- OnChange fires immediately after OnSelect only when it's the first time the payment option is selected. When the page and thus the Drop In is loaded it fires in order: OnSelect, OnReady, OnChange. So I can't check if the component is done loading.
  By default Ideal is selected. When you then select "Card" it fires OnSelect again and then OnChange 3 times. This also only happens the first time you select the "Card" payment option.

Is there a solid way to either:

- only track user changes?
- preload the options underneath a payment option, so that the changes don't get fired when the form is loaded?
- wait on form load when changing payment option selection

[image]

=============== CODE ===============================

```js
const configuration = {
  environment: this.model.environment || 'test',
  clientKey: this.model.clientKey,
  locale: this.model.locale,
  showPayButton: true,
  session: {
    id: this.model.sessionId,
    sessionData: this.model.sessionData,
  },
  onError: this.onFailed,
  paymentMethodsConfiguration: {
    ideal: {
      showImage: true
    },
    card: {
      hasHolderName: true,
      holderNameRequired: true,
    },
  },
  // https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-web/blob/master/packages/lib/src/language/locales/nl-NL.json
  translations: {
    'nl-NL': {
      payButton: this.$t('Veilig betalen').toString(),
      "idealIssuer.selectField.placeholder": this.$t('Kies uw bank').toString(),
      continue: this.$t('Veilig betalen')
    },
  },
  onChange: (state, component) => {
    console.log("ONCHANGE");
    if (this.tracking) {
      this.tracking.ecommerce.payment_method = state.data.paymentMethod.type;
      AnalyticsManager.getInstance().pushTracking(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.tracking)));
    }
  },
  onPaymentCompleted: (result, component) => {
    this.handleCompleted(result, component);
  },
};
```

```js
this.checkoutApi
  .create('dropin', {
    onReady: () => {
      console.log("OnReady");
    },
    onSelect: () => {
      console.log("ONSelect");
    }
  })
```

Comment: Hey Sebastiaan, can you give me some more info about your stack, and do you happen to have a working example I can have a look at ?

Comment: Hey @jlengrand thanks for your reply. I don't really have a working example that is publicly available unfortunately. I added my config object for the dropin and my create method to the question above.

In those I added logs to see which event fires when. When I load the page I see in order: OnSelect, OnReady, OnChange;

In this case the OnChange event shouldn't be tracked (because the user didn't do anything.

When I change from Ideal to Card I see in order: OnSelect, OnChange, OnChange, OnChange.

In this case the 3 OnChange events shouldn't be tracked.

Comment: Ok, I've been diving into it and I can reproduce the behaviour you're mentioning @sebastiaan. Let me come back to you about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also asked this in the GitHub for the Adyen DropIn.
https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-web/issues/2011#issuecomment-1460319246

In the OnChange event you can check if the form for that payment method is valid. I now check that and only track changes if the form is valid. This way no changes are tracked on page load.

```
                    onChange: (state, component) => {
                    if (this.tracking, state.isValid) {
                       //only do something when form valid
                    }
                },
```

Besides that I use the OnReady event to set a boolean. In the OnSelect method I only track changes if the boolean is true, so that I don't track changes on page load there.

```
                this.checkoutApi
                .create('dropin', {
                    onSelect: (state) => {
                        if (!this.isReady)
                            return;

                        //do something
                    },
                    onReady: () => {
                        this.isReady = true;
                    }
                })
```

Comment: Hey! oh my, apologies, I thought I had answered your question already. That's on me. Glad the folks on GitHub were more useful. The combination sounds indeed like what you wanna be doing. nice one!

Answer (score 1):

We're investigating the onChange behavior internally. In the meantime, you can use the `onSelect` [optional configuration event handler](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/web-drop-in/optional-configuration).

```
const checkout = await createAdyenCheckout(checkoutSessionResponse)
checkout.create(type, {
      onSelect: obj => console.log('Payment method Selected:', obj.props.name)
}).mount(document.getElementById(type));
```

This will do exactly what you need, by raising an event every time a customer selects a different enabled payment method.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I already use OnSelect which works fine (see code above). It fires once at pageload, but it does that before the OnReady event. This way you can choose wether you do something with it or not. So the only thing I think would be nice is if:
- OnChange also fires before OnReady or not at load.
- OnChange doens't fire after OnSelect so only user changes in the form can be tracked

Comment: I got an answer in the github that I used combined with the OnReady method. See my answer below. Thanks very much for your help!